# Greeting a friend saying 'yo'

Tags: greetings

I've heard in anime that close friends greet each other saying 'yo', as if it were the same in English when you say "yo!". I've been searching how to write it, but I have only found the common ways to greet (like `konichiwa`, etc). Does it have a kanji or do you write it using the hiragana `よ`?

Comment: To be honest I've never paid attention to it. If you could provide the name of the series maybe I could look it up in the manga. Usually manga has the same dialog and is practical to learn the writings particularly in long dialogs, i.e., Death Note.

Comment: It is よう.  よ is internet and texting slang.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

よ！　Only hiragana. You can find this kind of things by looking at online dictionaries like http://jisho.org/

Comment: I wouldn't say EDICT is particularly good for this sort of thing, it is missing tons of slang, even extremely related things like ちーっす

Comment: Well, I agree it's not as comprehensive as I wish it were, but the interjection "yo" isn't exactly the most obscure one either... and it's in there.